# Another way to say "open to public view"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

Is there another way to say

> The article was **open to public view**.

I want to describe a blog posted to a webpage.

Comment: "Open (or available) for public inspection" is typically the sort of language used when publishing laws, etc. Perhaps too clinical for a blog, though.

Comment: Do you refer only to the fact that a blog is technically available to the public or is any level of usage right implied, too?

Comment: Please provide additional context. With the limited context, I'd suggest "Unrestricted"... Also if you are looking from a licensing perspective, then "the article was not copy protected" or "..was not copyrighted" are good candidates. However, I feel that open to public view  conveys the intended meaning very well.

Answer (score 1):

'the article was publicly available'

or publicly browsable/searchable?

Comment: Good point – well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

**"This article is an open access publication"**.

> Example: *Another growing research-related activity of academic
>   libraries is the open access publication of the results of
>   publicly-funded research*.

If you mean that the article is not copyrighted, you may say that "The article is in the public domain".

> *When a work is in the public domain, it is free for use by anyone for any purpose without restriction under copyright law. Public domain is
>   the purest form of open/free, since no one owns or controls the
>   material in any way*.

Comment: This misses the point of what I understand the question to mean: "Open access" implies legal permission to consume or even reuse the content. I understand the question to only imply public accessibility in a very practical sense.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek - "Open access" covers  outputs that are free of all restrictions on access (e.g., access tolls). The contents may either be free of many restrictions (Creative commons, etc.) or may remain covered by various forms of intellectual property rights.

Answer (score 0):

I've used "publicly available" for similar instances. Depending on its copyright status, you could also consider "public domain."